# Fooling DB Query to Accept Alternate Values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table with a field named URL that displays values that look like this: Spain/Flower, Japan/Flag. So a URL might look like MySite/World/Spain/Bird

I want to group that project together with several others and merge them into a new website. The catch is the URL's have to change from Spain/Flower to Spain_Flower. In other words, I want to replace all the forward slashes with underscores.

In the query below, $MyURL (:MyURL) would equal the page URL, e.g. Spain/Bird. Can anyone suggest a way to make it accept Spain_URL as the correct URL instead? So if I type in the URL MySiteNew/Spain_Bird, it should display, but MySiteNew/Spain/Bird should fetch a 404 error message.

(I'm working with PHP/MySQL.)

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(num) as num FROM (
 SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM gs WHERE URL = :MyURL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM people WHERE URL = :MyURL
) AS X";
```

Comment: Are you trying to replace them in the database or just change them each time after you get them out of the database?

Comment: How are you getting your urls? Can you process the strings before your query? Are the urls being stored with underscores or slashes?

Comment: Oh, wait, I misunderstood the first time. Why don't you just use str_replace to change the underscores to slashes, then query the database?

Comment: @ willoller - the values are stored in the database like this: Spain/Flag

@ spc_tech - str_replace was the first thing I thought of. But it changes the URL, not the value stored in the database.

Comment: I'm also wondering if there could be a regex solution. The script would say "Accept a URL stored in the database that's exactly like the page URL except that it has a forward slash where there should be an underscore."

Comment: I'm wondering why you prefer a url that looks like "Spain_Bird" over a url that looks like "Spain/Bird". Personally I like the second option better, and it matches the way you are storing the urls.

Comment: Spain/Bird works great when dividing things into folders or creating a parent-child relationship (e.g. World > Europe > (a folder named Spain filled with articles about its flag, national flower, etc.), as I do on my current sites. But the new site will be organized more like Wikipedia, displaying thousands of articles on a single page. So I decided to style my URL's after Wikipedia. However, this is all tentative; I'm still trying to figure out the best way to do all of this...

Answer (score 1):

To generalize: you are looking for functionality called "Inflection", which is translating a word or phrase between different formats:

```
Inflect::camelCase('A nice string'); // ANiceString
Inflect::underscore('A nice string'); // a_nice_string
Inflect::humanize('a_nice_string'); // A Nice String
```

There are libraries for this kind of thing in various php frameworks: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html

and you could adapt/extend something like this to your exact needs:

```
Inflect::makeURL('MySite/Spain/Bird'); // MySite/Spain_Bird

class Inflect {
    public static function makeURL($string) {
        // This won't do exactly what you want but you get the idea
        return str_replace('/', '_', $string);
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks cool, but I'm not sure how to implement it. This is one attempt, but it doesn't work for obvious reasons.

Inflect::makeURL($MyURL);

class Inflect {
    public static function makeURL($String) {
        // This won't do exactly what you want but you get the idea
        return str_replace('/', '_', $String);
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT SUM(num) as num FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(Taxon) AS num FROM gz_life WHERE Taxon = :MyURL AND G1 = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM gs WHERE URL = :String AND G1 = 1

Comment: I'm viewing the URL MySite/Spain_Flag, which is similar to the database value Spain/Flag. But the way I modified my code, the script says "Display this page if the value in the database is Spain_Flag." So I need to do two things - 1) Make my script accept the database value Spain/Flag, 2) Make it then accept the URL Spain_Flag, even though it doesn't exactly match the database value. I'm probably just not implementing your script correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me - I knew there was a simple solution, but I didn't get it until now...

```
$String = str_replace('_', '/', $MyURL);

$sql = "SELECT SUM(num) as num FROM (
 SELECT COUNT(Taxon) AS num FROM gz_life WHERE Taxon = :MyURL AND G1 = 1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT COUNT(Name) AS num FROM gw_geog WHERE Name = :MyURL AND G1 = 1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM gs WHERE URL = :String AND G1 = 1
```

Comment: Acually, I should give spsc_tech credit for the right answer; I think that's essentially what he was telling me.